# Anyone can provide some example for updating google calendar data without the api provided by google In android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

As you know ...
In China ,the great fire wall is very strong... And the google's api  do not work sometimes ,and it do not support android so well.

So .. my boss want me to post the data to google server to update,delete or insert events manually without using google's api.

Any one can show me some **example** or tell me about what is the **format** of the data to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er..All right, I solved my problem by using batch operation.

In this page ,google provide some awesome method.

http://code.google.com/intl/zh/apis/gdata/docs/batch.html

They are really very easy to understand and use.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can take traffic sniffer, like Fiddler, make some request to google calendar in browser, and than take a look at what it looks like in sniffer. Than, just make request with necessary data yourself. Basically you want to emulate regular browser.

But in case of google services, I think, it might be a little bit hard. Supposedly you will have to parse a lot of keys, and other crap to look like real browser. Does it worth it?

Comment: Er... well , what I am trying is like what said.  I made a request to google server , but I do not know what format is correct ,and the information from google is not so sufficient about this way.  BTW , thank you very much , I will go to search "Fiddler"... I don't know it actually .

Comment: Well, that's why you need sniffer. It will show you what "key-value" pairs are being sent to server. I think, you can also use FireBug for this.

Comment: I tried FireBug....  Unluckily google do not use xml but cookie to update data...   Maybe I must find another way.

Comment: I checked the google api ,there are some methods to post data in xml , but not in detail.  Do you know something about it?